# Attaching VBA Form to Outlook Application

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm creating a custom form for appointments in Outlook for a project (add catering request to a meeting) - this is my first rodeo at doing this - and I'm striking out big time regardless of my intense (and failing) Google-Fu.

With a new appointment open, on the developer tab, I select "Design This Form".  I go to tab "(P.2)" and build a stupid-simple, two-object form... CheckBox1 and TextBox1.  In properties, TextBox1.Visible is False.  Click View Code and input the following...

```
   Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    if CheckBox1.value=True Then
      Me.TextBox1.Visible = True
     Else Me.TextBox1.Visible = False
    End If  
   End sub
```

I then click "Run This Form" and see/click CheckBox1 but nothing happens. If I could make this run, I might be in business. But it won't. So, I look for a work-around.

Grasping at straws, I open "Visual Basic" and basically do the same thing - create a form "UserForm1" with the same two objects and add the same code.  Click the go-button and it works as expected. The TextBox1 appears and disappears with the CheckBox1 state.

As I can make the code function, I would build everything I need in the Visual Basic editor, however... Here's the problem - I have absolutely **no** idea how to get the form I create here into the Outlook application as a tab or button or whatever. I basically want the custom form [VBA editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n5hu.png) to be a selectable option in any Appointment. 
I have watched tutorials, read doc, saw something about creating a macro - but nothing was written/stated dumbed-down enough for me to follow.

So my question: How do I get the UserForm1 that's built in VBA Editor to appear in a New Appointment when a button is clicked in Outlook?

Comment: FWIW that conditional assignment could be simplified to `Me.TextBox1.Visible = (Me.CheckBox1.Value)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `Click` event handler for the CheckBox control, not just paste the code to your custom form.

Following the June 13 2017 security update, users discovered published custom forms no longer worked because VBScript behind the form and some controls are blocked by default. See [Custom Form Security Changes](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/custom-form-security/) and [Custom form script is now disabled by default](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Custom-form-script-is-now-disabled-by-default-bd8ea308-733f-4728-bfcc-d7cce0120e94) for more information.

Microsoft disabled custom form script functionality. If you need it enabled, you'll need to set two keys, one to enable scripting and a second one with the message class name of each form that has code behind it. For example:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security
DWORD: DisableCustomFormItemScript
Value: 0 (to enable)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Forms\TrustedFormScriptList
REG_SZ: IPM.Contact.custom-form-name
Value: (leave blank)
```

In some cases, forms in secondary mailboxes and Public folders still don't work after the registry key settings. To fix this, enable scripts in the Trust Center:

1. Click `File` > `Options`. Then select `Trust Center` > `Trust Center Settings` > `Email Security`.
2. Under the `Script in Folders` section, click the checkbox for `Allow script in shared folders` and `Allow script in Public folders` and click `OK` and `OK` again to close out the windows.

Comment: Note: changing these settings effectively rolls back a security vulnerability patch - apply cautiously.